# All OnClickListeners react in one moment, when activity start

Tags: android, view, android-activity, onclick, onclicklistener

I have activity with `ListView`. I need to add several items to `userWillGo` and add `OnClickListener` to them.

This is a simple code, which doesn't work, because I get reaction of all items `OnClickListeners` only when the activity starts.

```
    public class UserDetailActivity extends Activity{
    ...
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.l_user_detail);

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("class");
            ...

            userWillGo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linerLayout_userDetail_willGoTO);
            if (user.getUserWillGo().size() > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < user.getUserWillGo().size(); i++) {
                    View myView = (View) LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, userWillGo, false);
                    ...
                    myView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener(this, curentEvent));
                    userWillGo.addView(myView);
                }

                ...
        }

        private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener(UserDetailActivity userDetailActivity, Event curentEvent) {
            Intent i = new Intent(userDetailActivity, EventDetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("class", curentEvent);
            startActivity(i);
            return null;
        }
```

Help to fix this bug. Thnx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declared `mOnClickListener` as a function that returns `null`, but its name suggests you want `mOnClickListener` to be a variable...

```
private View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener(UserDetailActivity userDetailActivity, Event curentEvent) {
    ...
    return null;
}
```

You need to create a custom class to accept your parameters, create an instance of this class, and use it instead.

---

On second thought you can use something like:

```
private View.OnClickListener createOnClickListener(UserDetailActivity userDetailActivity, final Event currentEvent) {
    return new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), EventDetailActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("class", currentEvent);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
}
```

(With this version you don't even need `userDetailActivity`.)

Comment: I understand, thnx. I'll try.

Comment: @SimonZettervall Not every answer needs example code, though I was writing some already. Remember the goal of SO isn't to do the work for you, but teach you how to do it.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Thanks, I wanted to mention that, but I forgot.